# Django Rest API merging delete/get/update/get methond in two class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

At first you see my 4 method class in `view.py:`

```
class ContactList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers

# This is delete method
class ContactDelete(DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers
    lookup_field = 'pk'

#below is post method to create new contact
class ContactCreate(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers

#below is put and patch method to update contact
class ContactUpdate(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

I want `ContactList` and `ContactCreate` should be in one class

and `ContactDelete` and `ContactUpdate` should be in one class

i am not getting how to merge it, can anyone tell me how to do it?

**Note: i dont want `APIViewSet`**

Comment: Is there any problem if you merge all these four class into one class?

Comment: Yes, it is problem

Comment: What problem? I think that's more appropriate and cleaner way

Comment: You are talking about viewset?

Comment: Yes, it is cleaner way but i have another purpose to use it, this is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF has already to classes for that purpose. You can check them [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) and [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrievedestroyapiview)

```py
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveDestroyAPIView


class ContactCreateListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers


class ContactRetrieveDeleteAPIView(RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
# This is create and list method
class ContactListCreate(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers


# This is delete and update method
class ContactDeleteUpdate(DestroyAPIView, UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializers
```

You can remove **`lookup_field = 'pk'`** from the view, since DRF took **`pk`** as the default value.